# SQL Get Order by 2 date colums when join 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

My tables:

```
T1 = Projects
T2 = bid_details
T3 = bid_submission_details
T4 = quote_submission_details
```

This is how Data flow Works:

[image: This is how Data flow Works]
SQL Code:

```
"SELECT *,T3.bidsubmit_date,T4.Quotesubmit_date FROM `Projects` T1
   LEFT JOIN `bid_details` T2 ON(T2.proj_reff = T1.proj_reff) 
   LEFT JOIN `bid_submission_details` T3 ON(T3.bid_reff = T2.bid_reff)
   LEFT JOIN `quote_submission_details` T4 ON(T4.proj_reff = T1.proj_reff)
ORDER BY T3.bidsubmit_date,T4.Quotesubmit_date ASC";
```

Result View:

### [image]

I have tried many ways to ORDER BY the submission date. but nothing worked. In the result view blue highlighted row is 2014 dated but it not going at the top of the list when I Order by Ascending order.

It always Orders the result from Quote Submission table first and then Order the result from Bid Submission table. Project types can be seen the in the result view.

i want a way to get Order by **submission date** no matter what type of project it is!

Comment: that's how orderby works. it'll sort the fields in the order they're specified. first it sorts ALL Of the records by their bidsubmitdate. Once that's done, within any single bidsubmitdate value, any records with that same bidsubmitdate will be sorted by their quotesubmitdate.

Comment: Furthermore, I wonder if anything is being done between the time the resultset comes back from the database and your software displays it. The "Results View" above is clearly very formatted from the actual result set. Could your presentation layer be reordering away from your expectations?

Comment: your query statement doesn't match the result.

Comment: Despite the header, the result sure does seem sorted by project name.  So, as JNevill suggests, check the client for an overriding SEQ.  (I always teach my staff to sort in the client when possible (and let SQL pick its nature order for its most efficient execution plan))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using COALESCE() function to the filed from the other three tables together.

```
SELECT *,T3.bidsubmit_date,T4.sub_date,
  COALESCE(T3.bidsubmit_date,T4.sub_date) AS SubmiDates
FROM `$SQLTable` T1
  LEFT JOIN `quote_submission_details` T4 ON(T4.pro_ref_no = T1.ref_no)
  LEFT JOIN `bid_details` T2 ON(T2.pro_ref_no = T1.ref_no) 
  LEFT JOIN `bid_submission_details` T3 ON(T3.bid_ref_no = T2.bid_ref_no) 
ORDER BY SubmiDates ASC";
```

after many very much goggling found a solution !!!